# R running on a server - unable to change default library and to install packages

Tags: r, remote-server

I searched the forum extensively and found that many people have already asked how to set their own library directory. I also ran help(Startup) but unfortunately I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

Probably my case is a bit different. The R version I work with is stored on a server of the National Bureau of Statistics. Therefore, I cannot access the Renviron.site file located on C:/. I can only access a shared disk called H:/. Nevertheless, no matter how many times I try to set my own directory typing .libPaths("H:/"), when I check again using .libPaths() R tells that the only place where I can install packages is the original location on C: - so it doesn't record the command. But actually I can't install packages there because when I try, R says that C: is not writable.

What can I do? Has anybody already encountered a problem like this?

Comment: You need to specify a complete path to a directory for which you do have permission. Just typing a directory root will not generally be sufficient on Windows devices with permissions set m=by sysadmins.

Comment: Do you have access to set **R_LIBS** variable on the server?

Comment: I don't know. If it is another file stored on C:/ the answer is no. Do you think I can try to modify that usign the command line? If so, how can I do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to use a directory you have writing access to, e.g. `H:/users/me/my_libs` instead of `H:/` like DWin suggested?

Comment: @flodel Yes, I tried but nothing works. This I found out is done on purpose by the institution who owns the data. They completely block R's access to the internet and make it even impossible to copy-paste packages into your shared folders (H:/). On request, they simply install the packages for you... It is a bit of a paranoid behavior, but I have to get over it, I suppose.